# send custom settings for the component with the final application

Tags: delphi, resources, delphi-7, custom-component

i am working in `Delphi-7` on a component that basically creates a zip file and has 5 features (below)

1] Folder

2] Images

3] text files

4] Create a Folder of the zip file in Application directory Or the application data directory

5] Create Zip file or not

The component will be dropped onto a **form**. Now i have another application (**settingAppl**) from which the user can actually decide to enable any of the `5` features for the component.
Everything is working fine as i have saved the user-selected settings in the `registry`. Rather than using the registry (i am not sure if its a good idea to send the registry *.reg with the component), I used a DAT file [About.com_fileof_delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/fileio/a/fileof_delphi.htm) to which **settingAppl** will write the 5 settings.  I need to send the file with the application that will have the component so that it can read the 5 settings.

Is there a way that i can directly set the 5 settings into the component as i am stuck what to do if the file is missing from the application directory?

Like Eureka log does, can any one tell me how to do something similar to this? Meaning when we set the settings in eureka logs , the programmer doesn't have to include/send a file along with the final application

[image]

Comment: Use published properties just as you do for any other component.

Comment: Use component `Constructor` method to set property default values. Save those values to `Registry` either when application is first run or after user has made any changes.

Comment: @LightBulb, you don't need the registry at all. You can store them as published properties in the DFM file, and no external storage is needed.

Comment: How do i do the storing from an external application?

Comment: You don't need an external application. Your component is dropped onto a form. If you don't store its properties in the .dfm file then that would be plain weird. Why do you need an external app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through @david  and @Ken White idea
(Which was much simpler than the idea i had in mind..also better (way)).i introduced the `published` properties into the component like this

```
private
  { Private declarations }
  FFolderzip  ,Fimagezip,Ftextzip      : Boolean;
  FMessagebo : string;
published
   { Published declarations }
   {component Properties}
   {#1.Folder Zip}
   property ZipFolder : Boolean read FFolderzip  write FFolderzip  default False;
   {#2.Send imagezip ?}
   property ZipImage : Boolean read Fimagezip   write Fimagezip   default False;
   {#3.text files}
   property ZipText : Boolean read Ftextzip   write Ftextzip   default False;
   {#4.message}
   property ZipMessage: String read FMessagebo write FMessagebo ; 
    ....
 end;
```

Then to access the properties

```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
       bZipFolder,bZipImage,bZipText: boolean;
       sMessage : string;
   begin
       bZipFolder:=zipperCom1.ZipFolder ;
       bZipImage :=zipperCom1.ZipImage; 
       bZipText  :=zipperCom1.ZipText; 
       sMessage  :=zipperCom1.ZipMessage;
    end;
```

Source for extra reference :-

1] [ADDWriteToReadOnlyProps](http://www.evocorp.com/Delphi/ADDWriteToReadOnlyProps.htm)

2] [Delphi-property](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/property.html)

Comment: It's a  much better solution, but your names are confusing. :-) If you change them somewhat, they'll be much easier to read and understand. For instance, instead of `FolderZip`, `ImageZip` and `TextZip` use `ZipFolder`, `ZipImage`, and `ZipText`, and then setting  them to `true` or `false` makes more sense. `bZipFolder := zipperCom1.ZipFolder;' reads better. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite suggestion appreciated :) i made the changes to the actual code too